# How can i access sharepoint using LINQ instead of CAML?

Tags: list, caml-query, linq

is there any way to access Sharepoint lists via LINQ instead of CaML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/hh135094.aspx

and for an error that occurs often, here:

http://collaborationnation.blogspot.com/2008/09/feature-guid-for-list-template-xxx-is.html

Sorry, I dont want to sound rude, but these are the first google results..

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SP 2010, You can access SP Lists by using SPMetal.
Though SPMetal ignores few fields like Modified, Created etc. You can include these fields using an XML file consisting of parameters.

Follow the link for using SPMetal with Parameters -

http://yogeshlotlikar.wordpress.com/2012/03/22/using-spmetal-parameters/